# Wordpress FLIR (Facelift Image Replacement) plugin clipping off end of text

Tags: plugins, customization

I'm using the FLIR for Wordpress plugin (v0.8.9.2) with FancyFonts enabled. I'm running Wordpress 3.1. The problem I'm having is that it appears the plugin is cutting off a couple pixels off of the end of some of the text that it generates. It doesn't do it for all text, but where it happens, it happens consistently.

Here are some examples:

[image]

[image]

[image]

In my search for a solution, I've found a number of people with this issue, but never any solutions. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Seems like the plugin has a bug. The plugin doesn't seem to be actively maintained anyway, but your best bet is to contact the plugin author. The cufon project is pretty similar and production proven. Just google for it. But in times of CSS3 and HTML5 you could simply insert the font via @font-face.

Comment: @marvinhagemeister -- Thanks for your suggestions! They are much appreciated. If you want to enter it as an actual answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy & Paste from comment.

Seems like the plugin has a bug. The plugin doesn't seem to be actively maintained anyway, but your best bet is to contact the plugin author. The cufon project is pretty similar and production proven. Just google for it. But in times of CSS3 and HTML5 you could simply insert the font via @font-face.

Edit: It is totally safe to use @font-face these days. IE actually supports font-face since IE4 via the .eot format. Not as nice as using the .otf like modern browsers do, but far better than any other solution.